# Counting ListRows in table using C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop, listobject

I am currently trying to get a count of rows that contain data within a table. I understand that I am able to get total table rows with

```
int TSize = xlSheet.ListObjects[CurrentTable].ListRows.Count;
```

however, I'd like to get the current populated table size. Ex: I may have 20 filled rows within a 200 row table. How can I get the count of 20 instead of 200? Is there a fast way to this, or will I need to iterate each row that contains content?

Thanks ahead of time!